# Printing Barcode TSC Labels via Python with a input variable

Tags: python, variables, barcode

Hi stackoverflowmembers,

unfortunately, after a lot of attempts I am a bit desperate. 
I would be really grateful for help.
It's probably because I'm an absolute beginner in Python.

With a small program I would like to print barcodes on my TSC-TDP 225 barcode printer.
I would like to print an input variable, which I do not succeed. Is there the input command at the point at all right or do I have to convert something there?

Enclosed my code with one of my attempts:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
"""
Spyder Editor
"""

import ctypes
#import subprocess

mydll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('C:\DEVELOP\BARCODE\TSCLIB.dll')
print ("Start Printing")
mydll.openportW("TSC_TDP-225")
mydll.setup("32","25","5","10","0","0","0")
mydll.clearbuffer()

"""
#Input variable
#bc = input("BARCODE: ")                   
#print(bc)
"""

# LABEL TEMPLATE
mydll.sendcommandW("SIZE 41.5 mm,25.0 mm")
mydll.sendcommandW('GAP 3 mm,0 mm')
mydll.sendcommandW('DIRECTION 0')
mydll.sendcommandW('CLS')

# DRAW LABEL IMAGE
"""
#Some try...
#mydll.barcodeW("260","159","25","102","1","180","2","6", "$_GET['bc']");
#mydll.barcodeW("260","159","25","102","1","180","2","6", @(bc));
#subprocess.call(["mydll.barcodeW("260","159","25","102","1","180","2","6","'+bc+'"']);
"""

#Barcode works in line
mydll.barcodeW("260","159","25","102","1","180","2","6","1234567810");

# PRINT
mydll.sendcommandW('PRINT 1,1')
mydll.closeport()
print ("Finished Printing")
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Are you trying to send raw commands to your barcode printer? If so, you should read its documentation, and perhaps provide it with your question too. The crux of your question though is what would you like to print? You’ll get a bytestring from the call to `input`, which you’ll need to encode to something your printer understands.

Comment: Just put `bc` where you have `"1234567810"` now.  You're making this far more complicated than it needs to be.